# Expo (React-native) - AdMob alternatives that work with managed workflow

Tags: react-native, expo, ads

Are there any advertising alternatives for Expo (Managed) other than the Facebook Ads `expo-ads-facebook` which seems to have known bugs causing it to not work with managed workflows?

I have been banned from Admob, I have no idea why - they said invalid traffic but I am not sure where that has come from.  I am wanting something to tide me over until the ban is lifted, but I cannot find anything where I don't have to eject to get it to work (which I really want to avoid if possible).

Thanks in advance.